# Usar el Resultado de un SELECT para ser usado en un JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy usando una query para intentar mostrar el nombre del ultimo usuario que haya realizado una entrada en la base de datos.

Para eso uso la siguiente Query:

```
SELECT
    (
    SELECT
        (
        SELECT
            posts.post_author_id
        FROM
            posts
        WHERE
            posts.forum_type_id = forum.id
        ORDER BY
            createdAt
        DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS Ultimo_Post, forum.forum_type, COUNT(*) AS forum_posts_count
FROM
    posts p,
    forum
WHERE
    p.forum_type_id = forum.id
GROUP BY
    p.forum_type_id
```

Al ejecutar esta Query me devuelve los siguientes resultados

[image: Resultado de la Query]

En este resultado estoy trayendo de manera exitosa el ID del **ultimo** usuario que haya realizado una entrada en el foro. Pero este ID no es lo que quiero mostrar en mi HTML.

Quisiera poder Relacionar ese ID que devuelve este trozo de codigo

```
        (
        SELECT
            posts.post_author_id
        FROM
            posts
        WHERE
            posts.forum_type_id = forum.id
        ORDER BY
            createdAt
        DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS Ultimo_Post
```

Con el ID de mis usuarios dentro de la tabla "usuarios".

Algo como un JOIN donde en el campo "**Ultimo_Post**" no me muestre un numero de ID sino el Login del usuario asociado a ese ID

Comment: No termino de comprender tu problema, por lo menos por lo que declaraste aca... No veo donde ese query devuelve el id... Y otra cosa... Esto anda porque es Mysql, en una base de datos ANSI no va a andar, ya que la condicion de group by no existe en el query.

Comment: `(
        SELECT
            posts.post_author_id
        FROM
            posts
        WHERE
            posts.forum_type_id = forum.id
        ORDER BY
            createdAt
        DESC
    LIMIT 1
    )`
Ese trozo de codigo es el encargado de seleccionar el ultimo post_author_id (id de usuario que ha creado el post). en la tabla de la foto se muestran los resultados de esta query y necesito coger ese id que resulta en la fila Ultimo_post y buscar la coincidencia en la tabla usuarios para que muestre el nombre de un usuario(usuarios.user_login) y no su nombre

Comment: o sea.. ultimo_post en realidad es post_author_id????

Comment: Si en efecto, y en otra query donde uso ese post_author_id para hacer un JOIN y que se muestre el login del usuario en vez de su ID. Dentro de la SELECT donde traigo el id del ultimo usuario que haya realizado una entrada me gustaria que dentro de esa misma select pueda yo sustituir el id del usuario resultante por su login relacionado

Comment: @JuanP Moreno, deberías leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) y editar tu pregunta para que podemos ayudarte a encontrar una respuesta satisfactoria a tu duda. Si clarificas qué tienes y qué necesitas nos ayudarás a ayudarte. Recuerda que cuanta más información de y más clara sea la pregunta, más probable es que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Cuando decis otra query, es para modificar esta query, o es otra query totalmente distinta.. o es que necesitas otra query, similar a esta, pero con ese cambio?

Comment: @gbianchi otra query distinta

Comment: Y donde esta esa otra query?  esa es la que tenemos que arreglar.. o no te estaria entendiendo

Comment: @Hermes creo que he sido un poco tacaño con el primer parrafo de mi pregunta pero pesaba que la habia formulado bien. Disculpadme voy a redactar una vez mas mi pregunta

Comment: @gbianchi primero gracias por tomarte tu tiempo de revisar mi problema de verdad, he vuelto a redactar mi pregunta a ver si me he explicado mejor esta vez

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias hacer el join directamente ahi y devolver el nombre que vos queres:

```
SELECT
    u.Nombre
FROM
    posts p inner join Usuarios u ON p.post_author_id = u.id
WHERE
    p.forum_type_id = forum.id
ORDER BY
    createdAt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

O tambien podrias cambiar el select y devolver un subselect, no se cual sera mas performante, eso depende de tu db, y de lo que diga el explain plan de la misma

```
SELECT
    (select u.Nombre from Usuarios u where u.id = p.post_author_id)
FROM
    posts p
WHERE
    p.forum_type_id = forum.id
ORDER BY
    createdAt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Perfecto!!, la segunda solución ha sido la que me ha funcionado, muchisimas gracias! un saludo